# Powershell script to search and replace text in a file using two columns in a separate reference file

Tags: powershell, command, command-prompt, prompt

I want  a script that can help me check for the name of keyset (column a) in Sample.cvs and then replace the current command(column b) with new command (column c) in the Source text file.

CSV file: Sample.csv

```
   A.         |     B.                |   C.
Manock        |     2B                |  2ab
Sterling      |     3F                |  3sf
```

Source file text: Source.txt

```
keyset "Manock"
(

    key("SELECT")
    command ("display/app=%disapp% "2B")

);
```

So desired output:

```
keyset "Manock"
(

    key("SELECT")
    command ("display/app=%disapp% "2ab")

);
```

Powershell Script:

New-Item -Path "C:\Users\e076200\Desktop\ks_update\source.txt" -ItemType File -Force

$data = Get-Content C:\Users\e076200\Desktop\ks_update\source.ddl

Add-Content -Value $data -Path "C:\Users\e076200\Desktop\ks_update\source.txt"

$foundline = $false

$a = 0

$Etxt = foreach($line in Get-Content C:\Users\e076200\Desktop\ks_update\source.txt)

{

if ($line -match 'keyset "Manock"' )

```
{

$a = 0

$foundline = $true
```

}

```
$a= $a + 1


if($line -match "display/app" -and $a -eq 5 -and $foundline -eq $true)

{

 $line = $line.replace('2b' , '2ab')



 $line




}

else

{

$line

}
```

}

$Etxt | Set-Content C:\Users\e076200\Desktop\ks_update\source.txt -Force

$users = Import-CSV -Path:\Users\e076200\Desktop\ks_update\sample.csv

I've figured out how to find and replace one line in the file directly. I've also figured out how to import the csv. I need help on how to make the logic parameterized and use column A of CSV as the match piece and column c as the replacement piece.

Script Explanation.

New-Item -Path "C:\Users\e076200\Desktop\ks_update\source.txt" -ItemType File -Force

- New-Item creates new text file @ location defined by -Path  using name specified at the end, source.
- ItemType to define type of document, -Force is force command.

$data = Get-Content C:\Users\e076200\Desktop\ks_update\source.ddl

- Retrieves ddl and stores in variable.

Add-Content -Value $data -Path "C:\Users\e076200\Desktop\ks_update\source.txt"

- Transfers content from variable to new text file  created.

$foundline = $false

- conditional variable defined for when keyset identifier is found.

$a = 0

- counter defined for if statement.

$Etxt = foreach($line in Get-Content C:\Users\e076200\Desktop\ks_update\source.txt)

- $Etxt - for loop
- $line - variable for each line in txt

{

if ($line -match 'keyset "Manock"' )

```
{

$a = 0

$foundline = $true
```

}

### If keyset identifier is found, set counter to 0 and set conditional variable to true

```
$a= $a + 1





if($line -match "display/app" -and $a -eq 5 -and $foundline -eq $true)

{

 $line = $line.replace('2b' , '2ab')



 $line
```

- Match found, PS runs logic, line with keyset identifier == 0 + 1....up until line = 5 where we find item to be replaced.
- For redundancy, line reader set to check for line identifier, ("display/app") on expected line.
- If Redundant check if met and counter is 5 then we replace word with the line.replace function.
- Overwritten data is returned in $line

  }

  else

  {

  $line

  }
- Else retain line

}

$Etxt | Set-Content C:\Users\e076200\Desktop\ks_update\source.txt -Force

- Updated text file

$users = Import-CSV -Path:\Users\e076200\Desktop\ks_update\sample.csv

- Imports Reference csv file
- Please make explanation as dumbed down as possible. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You forgot to ask a question. ;-)  Please take your time to do the [Tour] and read at least the help topic about [Ask] to set your expectations on SO. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are two ways: use heavy parser that parses this file exactly correct, OR to write simple parser. Provide example of whole file please, so users can get the syntax of rest of the file.

Comment: Read the csv into a table.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7.2